# How to disable Read Only from the Fields published by InfoPath in SP2010?

Tags: 2010, infopath, form-library

I have a InfoPath form published in SharePoint 2010. The form contains various fields which are published as Metadata in Library.

But all the fields are displaying as Read Only and I am not able to make that field as editable.

I don't have access to SharePoint Server, I just have SharePoint Document Library and SharePoint Designer.

PS: PowerShell script will not work as I am not having SharePoint Server.

Can any one let me know how can we make field editable that are published by InfoPath in SP2010?

Comment: Since you have permission for the document library, please try with CSOM code

Comment: So their types are "Manage Metadata", right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tarun for suggestion.

I ended up using CSOM.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;



namespace COM

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            string siteUrl = "http://serverName:46563/sites/MMS-CTH/";



            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            Web web = clientContext.Web;

            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");

            Field field = list.Fields.GetByTitle("Title");

            field.ReadOnlyField = true;

            field.Update();

            clientContext.Load(field);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(field.Title + " is updated successfully");

            Console.ReadLine();           

        }
    }
}
```

I found the reference [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/make-the-list-field-read-only-in-sharepoint-2010-using-client-object-model)